# How to show canadian dollar with PHPs Numberformatter?

Tags: php, numberformatter

how I can display the canadian Dollar, e.g. CA$ 12.00?

My current code is

```
$formatter = new NumberFormatter('en_CA', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$formatter->formatCurrency(123.33, 'en_CA');
```

My result is $123.33

Comment: That would be the expected output. The currency symbol for Canadian dollars is still just `$`, not `CA$`. See http://www.xe.com/currency/cad-canadian-dollar. Also note that the second argument to `formatCurrency` should be the ISO 4217 Currency Code for the desired currency. Being `CAD` in this case, not `en_CA`.

Comment: Are you trying to actually convert currency to CA$?  The Numberformatter class doesn't do that; it just correctly formats the number you give it.

Answer (score 0):

Ah ok.

if I use another locale, e.g. de_DE and currency CAD, then the output was CA$123.33

Thank you